# Stubbing the call of a super class method using Mockito(V 1.9.5)

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test a method whom depending on some conditions will execute its code or its super class's one.
Here is the code of the class and its parent:

```
public class ParentClass {

public Object doStuff(Parameters parameters) {
    // do some business stuff
    return parentResult;
}
}
```

The inherited class's one:

```
public class InheritedClass extends ParentClass {

@Override
public Object doStuff(Parameters parameters) {
    if (parameters.getCondition()) {
        return super.doStuff(parameters);
    }
    //do some business stuff
    return inheritedResult;
}
}
```

So, when trying to test the case when the parameters.getCondition() is true, I have to mock the call on the super method and verify it.

But when I do this (mocking the call for the super.doStuff()), I also mock the call to the InhertitedClass.doStuff().
Here's the solution I tried:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class InheritedClassTest {
@Mock
private Parameters parameters;

@Spy
private InheritedClass inherited = new InheritedClass();

@Test
public void testDoStuff(Object parameters) throws Exception {
    given(parameters.getCondition()).willReturn(true);
    doCallRealMethod().doReturn(value).when(inherited).doStuff(parameters);

    Mockito.verify(inherited, times(2)).doStuff(parameters);
}
}
```

I also tried this stubbing:

```
when(inherited.doStuff(parameters)).thenCallRealMethod().thenReturn(value);
```

and this one:

```
given(((ParentClass)inherited).doStuff(parameters)).willReturn(value);
```

In all this cases, the code of the parent class was really executed.
So, I was wondering if there is any efficient way to mock the call of the super class method using mockito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Mockito's spy(), which you already tried to do. But I think a different way of using spy() will make it work.

ParentClass.java

```
public class ParentClass {
    public String doStuff(final String parameters) {
        return "parent";
    }
}
```

InheritedClass.java

```
public class InheritedClass extends ParentClass {
    @Override
    public String doStuff(final String parameters) {
        if (parameters.equals("do parent")) {
            return super.doStuff(parameters);
        }
        return "child";
    }
}
```

InheritedClassTest.java

```
public class InheritedClassTest {
    @Test
    public void testDoStuff() throws Exception {
        final InheritedClass inheritedClass = Mockito.spy(new InheritedClass());

        Mockito.doReturn("mocked parent").when((ParentClass)inheritedClass).doStuff(Mockito.eq("do parent"));

        final String result = inheritedClass.doStuff("do parent");

        assertEquals("mocked parent", result);
        assertNotEquals("parent", result);

        final String resultChild = inheritedClass.doStuff("aaa");

        assertEquals("child", resultChild);
    }
}
```

**However, I do not think using spy() is a good practice. I would personally refactor your code.**